# Constructor method reference for (non-static) inner class?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Is there something equivalent for `StaticClass::new` for inner class given the outer class instance?

Edit:

I.e. if I have

```
class Outer {
    class Inner {
    }
}
```

I can do `Outer o = new Outer(); Inner i = o.new Inner()` in old Java. How can I express the `o.new Inner()` as function reference.

Comment: Could you add some code, i.e. where exactly the class is defined and where you want to use it?

Comment: Interestingly, in the example section of the [JLS on method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13), there is an example: `Outer.Inner::new` but that does not compile... They maybe meant `Outer.StaticNested::new`...

Comment: Not a method reference, but you could use a lambda like `() -> outer.new Inner()`

Comment: @assylias: `Outer.Inner::new` does work if you are *inside* `Outer`, i.e. if an instance of `Outer` is in scope. Of course, you could write just `Inner::new` then…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), there are four kinds of method references:

- Reference to a static method

  - `ContainingClass::staticMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of a particular object

  - `containingObject::instanceMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type

  - `ContainingType::methodName`
- Reference to a constructor

  - `ClassName::new`

References to a local/nested class are not listed, so I would assume it's not supported.

You can use the [`java.util.function.Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) to trigger the usage of lambdas in order to obtain an instance of the nested class:

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Supplier<Outer.Inner> supplier = () -> outer.new Inner();
```

Answer (score 6):

The [Chapter 15.13. Method Reference Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) in the JLS contains a somewhat cryptic statement about this:

> The immediately enclosing instance of a new inner class instance ([§15.9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.2)) is provided by a lexically enclosing instance of `this` ([§8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)).

This basically means that a method reference to the constructor of an inner class is possible *in* a method of the outer class, like in this example

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;
class Outer
{
    public class Inner
    {
    }
    void example()
    {
        Supplier<Inner> s = Inner::new;
    }
}
```

But the JLS does not mention any alternative, so one has to assume that it is simply not possible to provide the enclosing instance in any other form than being `this`.

Comment: Nice one. It's pretty much the same reason for which you can do `new Inner()` within the enclosing class only. :)

Answer (score 0):

For static nested class, you can refer to it using outer class - `OuterClass.NestedClass::new`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 2, 3};

        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(A.B::new);
    }

}

class A {

    public A(int x) {
        System.out.println("A created, x = " + x);
    }

    public static class B {

        public B(int x) {
            System.out.println("B created, x = " + x);
        }

    }

}
```

For inner class (nested non-static class), you can do `outerInstanceName.new InnerClass(...)`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 2, 3};

        A a = new A(500);

        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(x -> a.new B(x));
    }

}

public class A {

    public A(int x) {
        System.out.println("A created, x = " + x);
    }

    public class B {

        public B(int x) {
            System.out.println("B created, x = " + x);
        }

    }

}
```

My IDE suggests me to convert `x -> a.new B(x)` into `A.B::new`, but this doesn't compile, because B is not static - it belongs not to the class `A` but to the instance of class `A`. So answering your question - I think it is not possible and you will have to use `outerInstanceName.new InnerClass(...)`.